# How do i resize JTable according to JFrame size

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtable, layout-manager

I want to make a table using `JTable` in Java Eclipse. But when it's running it's size not following the frame size when I resize the frame.

I have to tried to add `BorderLayout` but the result is disorganized like this [table](http://prntscr.com/orw85d).

This is my code:

```
Object[][] data = {}; 

// Column Names 
Object[] columnNames = { "Keyword", "DA", "PA", "Title", "URL",  "Backlink", "Load Time" }; 

listTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { 
    listTableModel.addRow(new Object[] { list.get(i), "ICON", "ICON" }); 
}

table = new JTable(listTableModel);
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
scrollPane.setBounds(10, 58, 736, 228);
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
frame.setSize(764, 324); 
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The result is like this [table](http://prntscr.com/orw85d).

Comment: The short answer is: put the component (table, whatever..) into a constraint in a layout which will stretch it to fit the available space. E.G. the `CENTER` of a `BorderLayout`, a cell of a `GridLayout`, a cell of a `GridBagLayout` with appropriate constraints.. **Do not** try to guess the necessary size for a component. Let the layout figure that out when the frame is packed.

Comment: Oh, and the 'long answer' is a couple of tips: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.